# Group and Sum from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to Group 2 tables Based on the First two columns. I have successfully done this and code can be seen below. 
I need some help to SUM the remaining column from each of the tables and INSERT into my output table with a renamed column as can bee seen below.
In the output the FORECAST column is a result from the MI_STAT_TOTAL table and the SALES column is a result from the SALES_TOTAL table.

TABLE: MI_STAT_TOTAL

```
Planning_Hierarchy_2  Region_Description          Measure_Values
xx                    LATAM                        2   
yy                    ASPAC                        3
zz                    EMEA                         4
zz                    EMEA                         1
aa                    ASPAC                        1
```

TABLE: SALES_TOTAL

```
Product_Number        Region                      Item_Values
xx                    LATAM                        1  
yy                    ASPAC                        2
zz                    EMEA                         2
zz                    EMEA                         1
bb                    USA                          2
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT
TABLE: P2_Region_Unique

```
Product_Number        Region                      Forecast       Sales
xx                    LATAM                        2             1
yy                    ASPAC                        3             2
zz                    EMEA                         5             3 
aa                    ASPAC                        1
bb                    USA                                        2
```

Code below that considers only the GROUP BY between the two tables but not the SUM:

```
CREATE TABLE P2_Region_Unique (
  Product_Number VARCHAR(100),
  Region VARCHAR(13)
  );

INSERT INTO P2_Region_Unique
    SELECT s.Planning_Hierarchy_2 AS Product_Number, s.Region_Description` AS Region
    FROM MI_STAT_TOTAL s
    UNION
    SELECT m.`Product Number` AS `Product_Number`, m.`Region` AS Region
    FROM SALES_TOTAL m;
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT TABLE FORMAT considering that the SUM is also included

```
CREATE TABLE P2_Region_Unique (
  `Product Number` VARCHAR(100),
  `Region` VARCHAR(13),
  `Forecast` DECIMAL (20,10),
  `Sales` DECIMAL (20,10)
  );
```

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to store derived data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can turn a `SELECT` to an `INSERT` using the [`INSERT ... SELECT` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html).

You sample data indicates that you are dealing with a N-M join. The first thing to do is to move the aggregation into subqueries, as follows :

```
INSERT INTO P2_Region_Unique
SELECT s.product_number, s.region, f.forecast, s.sales
FROM
    (
        SELECT product_number, region, SUM(item_values) sales
        FROM SALES_TOTAL
        GROUP BY product_number, region
    ) s
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT planning_hierarchy_2 product_number, region_description region, SUM(measure_values) forecast
        FROM MI_STAT_TOTAL
        GROUP BY planning_hierarchy_2, region_description
    ) f ON f.product_number = s.product_number AND f.region = s.region
GROUP BY s.product_number, s.region
```

This will work but will not return records from *both* ends of the join. For that, you can emulate FULL OUTER JOIN (which, as pointed out by @Nick, is not supported in MySQL) with UNIONed queries, like :

```
INSERT INTO P2_Region_Unique
SELECT s.product_number, s.region, f.forecast, s.sales
FROM
    (
        SELECT product_number, region, SUM(item_values) sales
        FROM SALES_TOTAL
        GROUP BY product_number, region
    ) s
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT planning_hierarchy_2 product_number, region_description region, SUM(measure_values) forecast
        FROM MI_STAT_TOTAL
        GROUP BY planning_hierarchy_2, region_description
    ) f ON f.product_number = s.product_number AND f.region = s.region
GROUP BY s.product_number, s.region
UNION
SELECT f.product_number, f.region, f.forecast, s.sales
FROM
    (
        SELECT planning_hierarchy_2 product_number, region_description region, SUM(measure_values) forecast
        FROM MI_STAT_TOTAL
        GROUP BY planning_hierarchy_2, region_description
    ) f
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT product_number, region, SUM(item_values) sales
        FROM SALES_TOTAL
        GROUP BY product_number, region
    ) s ON f.product_number = s.product_number AND f.region = s.region
GROUP BY f.product_number, f.region
```

The `UNION` operator eliminates duplicates across subqueries.

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3p2USu4qy8ki39MLmiSZhM/2)** yields :

```
| product_number | region | forecast | sales |
| -------------- | ------ | -------- | ----- |
| aa             | ASPAC  | 1        |       |
| bb             | USA    |          | 2     |
| xx             | LATAM  | 2        | 1     |
| yy             | ASPAC  | 3        | 2     |
| zz             | EMEA   | 5        | 3     |
```

Comment: As of Feb 2019, *no* versions of MySQL support `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @Nick : ahh ok, I was not aware of that, thanks ! OK so I rolled back my answer to the previous version, which did not make use of `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @GMB in your code is there any way to do a full outer join without using the FULL OUTER JOIN statement since it is not valid ?

Comment: @bp123 : yes exactly, the last query actually emulates the behavior of a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @GMB thank you very much, I tried running the code last night and it was running without any errors, and looked in the morning and it was still running. I cancelled it now as it was an endless loop. I believe there is an error somewhere, I tried debugging but could not identify. I believe it may be to do with the naming of the columns, I updated my question above to match the _ between words to make it easier. Please note the difference in naming between the columns of the different input tables and then what the output column in output table should look like in the example above. Thank you

Comment: @bp123 : ok, I gave a good luck as your sample data and expected output, and updated my answer with new queries, along with a DB Fiddle where queries are working fine. I expect that this should work for you too... Please let me know !

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select 
  s.ProductNumber,
  s.Region,
  sum(measureValues) Forecast,
  sum(itemValues) Sales
from MI_STAT_TOTAL m
FULL OUTER join SALES_TOTAL s
  on m.PlanningHierarcy2 = s.ProductNumber
group by
  s.ProductNumber,
  s.Region
```

for insert operation

```
 INSERT INTO P2_Region_Unique
    select 
      s.ProductNumber,
      s.Region,
      sum(measureValues) Forecast,
      sum(itemValues) Sales
    from MI_STAT_TOTAL m
    FULL OUTER join SALES_TOTAL s
      on m.PlanningHierarcy2 = s.ProductNumber
    group by
      s.ProductNumber,
      s.Region
```

if your MySQL version is below Version 8 Then

```
select 
  s.ProductNumber,
  s.Region,
  sum(measureValues) Forecast,
  sum(itemValues) Sales
from 
(
  SELECT * from MI_STAT_TOTAL m
  LEFT join SALES_TOTAL s
    on m.PlanningHierarcy2 = s.ProductNumber
  union 
  SELECT * from MI_STAT_TOTAL m
  RIGHT JOIN SALES_TOTAL s
    on m.PlanningHierarcy2 = s.ProductNumber
)
group by
  s.ProductNumber,
  s.Region
```

Comment: thank you @simonare . I updated the question slightly wherein we have an item that is existing in one table but not in the other. However in the output table, I would still like to see this result . Please check the expected output above. Can you pls update your code to reflect this ?

Comment: you can use FULL OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Comment: As of Feb 2019, *no* versions of MySQL support `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @Nick yes I am getting an error when using full outer join